# How to install Railo on an Amazon Linux instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, railo, cfml

I have setup a new Amazon Linux instance, what are the next steps to install Railo on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On first login you will get the 'Message of the Day ' asking to update additional tools. To install updates just type in the command prompt

```
sudo yum update
```

Before you can install Railo install Apache to handle all web traffic i.e 80.

```
sudo yum install httpd httpd-devel
```

Next make sure make sure the service is loaded at startup of the instance.

```
sudo chkconfig --level 2345 httpd on
```

Now navigate to the instance in a browser. You may need to allow traffic on port 80 in your security group. I just edited my security group to allow http traffic on that port from within the AWS console.

Next to install Railo started by creating a directory to download Railo into.

```
sudo mkdir /temp
```

Then CD into this folder.

```
cd /temp
```

Next download Ralio to the newly created folder.

```
sudo wget http://www.getrailo.org/down.cfm?item=/railo/remote/download/4.0.0.013/tomcat/linux/railo-4.0.0.013-BETA2-linux-x64-installer.run
```

Replace above URL with the most current stable release.

Before ruining the installer make sure to change the permission on the file you just downloaded in this case...

```
sudo chmod 777 railo-4.0.0.013-BETA2-linux-x64-installer.run
```

Run the installer

```
sudo ./ railo-4.0.0.013-BETA2-linux-x64-installer.run
```

Railo should now be running on port 8888.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add... Make sure you store all your files including any configuration files, MYSQL data files and logs on an EC2 volume so you can take advantage of snapshots.  This includes backing up your instance to EBS as well.

Nothing is more fun than having your EC2 instance disappear with no ability to recover. ;)